# Add on for Document Library Printing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, printing

Can any one please recommend any ad-ons for complete document library printing - without having to go into each document one by one? on 0365 Sharepoint2013 online?

Other than sharepointprinting.com

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate post - actually i was more so looking for an app to do this as users( content readers) without editing privileges will be the ones to get in there and actually print. They wont be able to go into explorer view

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround to do that .

- Go to Document library > Click on `Open with Explorer`.
- Select all ( CTRL+ A ) Document files > Right Click and Select Print.

[image]

- Select your printer , and you can also check the number of documents that will be printed .

[image]

**Note :** There's a limitation with this method where you can print only the files with the same extensions. so you can filter the same extension from above search textbox in windows explorer as `*.doc` I think it's also useful than print documents one by one

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate post - actually i was more so looking for an app to do this as users( content readers) without editing privileges will be the ones to get in there and actually print. They wont be able to go into explorer view